# How to get transform delta values when moving an object

Tags: scripting, drivers

When I move an object the transform delta values (Dx, Dy, Dz) are displayed in the top left of the 3d context window. Can those values be captured for use in scripted driver functions?

edit: It is the live delta information I want to try to access. These numbers are displayed and updated as you move the object. I want those values to be affecting the object with the driver, in the same way that the 'single property' var for x location (for example) does.

edit edit: Not sure if adding edits helps or a whole new question is in order, but I found a pic in the api of what I mean:

[image]

These delta values update "live" as you move the object. Is there a way to access these live values as they update. The answers posted don't address this issue but offer solutions to getting the result of the translation at the conclusion of the action.

Comment: Your image is from the documentation, not the api. You can't get those values. You can create a modal operator to implement e.g. translation. This sounds like an X, Y problem. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @Leander. Thanks. Yes, that's a screen grab from the docs. I used it because it's impossible to get a screen grab of the delta values as they appear in the upper left of the view3d screen. But you've answered the question: No, you can't access the values. I had already looked at modals and was hoping for something easier. I'm working on a script that may do what I need. Will post it if I can get it working.

Comment: Glad you're on it, but seriously: *This sounds like an X, Y problem. What is it you actually want to do?*

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the old slow parent functionality (I think), that mysteriously disappeared in 2.8. I want to select an object and have another object follow it around. But in a very specific way that I am still deciding upon, hence the "how to do x in order to do y" frame of question. Essentially I want some way of capturing the objects movement history in time.